# Looking for some approach to put 'moving image' over video (youtube video)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

What I need is this:

Overlay image which can change its X and Y position over youtube video without page reload.

Ideally this should be Javascript I guess which upon Interval gets the X and Y values from text file (or MySQL).

In other words...say a car is driving in the Youtube video, the overlay should be red rectangle that every 1 second or so the Javascript gets the X and Y from text file and redraws over the youtube screen red rectagle.

The final result should be something like this:

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/aEBigBm7KBk/hqdefault.jpg

I am C++/C# kind of guy with very little knowledge of Javascript so I want to port a machine learning demo to a friendly interface (webpage), I know this can be too much coding so if someone can at least point me to a free script will be super helpful! thanks!

Comment: OK this can be good start for me for now....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2kev63mq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've prepared a sample JSFiddle that can get you started in the right direction: https://jsfiddle.net/2nfswab3/

Basically, the `<div class="overlay"...` are the red squares that overlay the video. You may add as many as you like of them inside the #app container. You mentioned that their position will be changing dynamically every second with values coming from your backend code. Changing their position is as easy as updating their `left, right, top, bottom` CSS attributes.

You can do that through vanilla JS in this way:

```
var redSquares = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay');
var squareOne = redSquares[0];
squareOne.style.left = '300px';
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <iframe width="100%" height="400px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KGN_9xZBgYY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <div class="overlay" style="left: 370px; top: 140px;"></div>
  <div class="overlay" style="left: 170px; top: 140px;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#app{
  position: relative;
}
.overlay{
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: #fff;
  z-index:2;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

I hope this helps. If you have further need of help or elaboration please ask as a comment.

Comment: thanks alot! i will now try to mix your approach with what i discovered earlier: http://jsfiddle.net/2kev63mq/1/ and let you know also likely will pick yours as best answer.